# Compare generic-interface-type to given type

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I'm trying to dynamically create an instance of a type which inherits from a generic `interface`.

For example I have the following base-interface, where several other interfaces are derived from:

```
public interface IDummy { }
```

And I have two derived interfaces:

```
public interface IDummyDerived<T> : IDummy
{
  void Foo(T value);
}

public interface ITempDerived<T> : IDummy
{
  void HelloWorld(T value);
}
```

Now I need a ServiceProvider-Class where I can create find the classes which implementing the given interface. Each interface (IDummyDerived and ITempDerived) is implemented exactly once.

My approach would be:

```
internal class DummyServiceProvider
{
  public T GetDummy<T>() where T : IDummy
  {
    Type baseType = typeof(IDummy);
    Type[] types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(p => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass).ToArray();
    //now I have all classes which implements one of my interfaces
    foreach(Type type in types)
    {
      // here I want to check if the current type is typeof(T)
      // (typeof(T) == type) ->  doesn't work
      // (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type) doesnt work

    }
  }
  return default(T);
}
```

How can I correctly compare the given `typeof(T)` to a type in the types-array?

-- Update:

The usage of the DummyServiceProvider would look like:

`IDummyDerived<string> dummyDerived = myDummyServiceProvider.GetDummy<IDummyDerived<string>>()`

Comment: I see definition for `IDummyDerived<T>` but not for `IDummyDerived`.  Without having definition of `IDummyDerived` the code will not compile and should throw compilation error as `Using the generic type 'IDummyDerived<T>' requires 1 type arguments`. Is your question missing some code?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the generic-type in the call to the serviceprovider

Comment: Please check the posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to rewrite your where as follows

```
string nameOfIDummy = typeof(IDummy).Name;
string nameOfT = typeof(T).Name;
IEnumerable<Type> classTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(p => p.IsClass && p.GetInterface(nameOfIDummy) != null && p.GetInterface(nameOfT ) != null);
```

Maybe you could write what you need that for, I dont get the use case and for me it seems like a strange thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the equality between `base generic interface type` with `derived type` which would always be false:

See the below code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDummy { }

    public interface IDummyDerived<T> : IDummy
    {
        void Foo(T value);
    }

    public interface ITempDerived<T> : IDummy
    {
        void HelloWorld(T value);
    }

    public class DummyDerived<T> : IDummyDerived<T>
    {
        public void Foo(T value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DummyDerived`1 ->Foo");
        }
    }

    public class AnotherDummy : IDummyDerived<string>
    {
        public void Foo(string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AnotherDummy -> Foo");
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Is {typeof(DummyDerived<MyClass>)} equal to {typeof(IDummyDerived<MyClass>)} : {CheckType<DummyDerived<MyClass>>(typeof(IDummyDerived<MyClass>))}");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
            GetDummy<IDummyDerived<string>>();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool CheckType<T>(Type type)
        {
            return typeof(T) == type ? true : false;
        }

        public static T GetDummy<T>() where T : IDummy
        {
            Type baseType = typeof(IDummy);
            Type[] types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(p => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass).ToArray();
            //now I have all classes which implements one of my interfaces
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Is {type.Name} assignable from {typeof(T)} : {typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)}");
            }

            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the output as

> Is AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp.DummyDerived`1[AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp.MyClass] equal to AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp.IDummyDerived`1[AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp.MyClass] : False`
>
> ---
>
> Is DummyDerived`1 assignable from AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp.IDummyDerived`1[System.String] : False
>
> Is AnotherDummy assignable from AssemblyLoadRefelectionExp.IDummyDerived`1[System.String] : True

If you check in the above code, to check the base type with derived type, I've used here `IsAssignableFrom` method as since the `GetDummy` method is being invoked with `base generic interface type`. `IsAssignableFrom` validates that an instance of a specified type can be assigned to an instance of the current type.